# InitializeComponent Performance on Separate Thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

We are experiencing some bad performance on the InitializeComponent method of a WPF custom control we created containing about 10 UI elements.

This custom control is used to create a FixedDocument in another STA thread. The problem appears when some other UI elements (pages created on the main UI thread) are instantiated PRIOR to the FixedDocument creation.

If the user navigate to certain pages before, the problems appears, otherwise everything goes fine.

I have no idea why this is happening, but we are sure the issue is on the InitializeComponent method calls, that is taking about 2 seconds to complete.

The average memory usage of the app is about 100 MB and creating the FixedDocument does not use much more memory.

Here is the code that creates the document:

```
private Task<string> CreateLabels()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();

                //Each item is a tinny ViewModel object to populate LabelView
                foreach (var item in _labelsToPrint)
                {
                    double pageWidth = 96 * 4.0;
                    double pageHeight = 96 * 2.12;

                    LabelView lv = new LabelView(item);
                    lv.Width = pageWidth;
                    lv.Height = pageHeight;

                    FixedPage fp = new FixedPage();
                    fp.Width = pageWidth;
                    fp.Height = pageHeight;

                    fp.Children.Add(lv);

                    PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
                    pageContent.Child = fp;

                    fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);
                }

                FileInfo tempFile = new FileInfo(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".xps");
                var paginator = fixedDoc.DocumentPaginator;
                var xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(tempFile.FullName, FileAccess.Write);
                var documentWriter = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDocument);
                documentWriter.Write(paginator);
                xpsDocument.Close();

                tcs.SetResult(tempFile.FullName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tcs.SetException(ex);
            }

        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Is there any problem with multiple STA threads (the main UI and my own) running at the same time?

Thank you,

Comment: I think it's just code placement error you should write code before the error place.
for more assistance Upload the code so we can help!!!

Comment: Please have a look on the code.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to fix. My custom control was referencing the localization extension (http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com).

I removed this reference and everything is working fast now.

Still, do not have any idea why this extension is causing problems. I had to make string localization on the ViewModel class instead.